# Integer representation of a (fraction) modulo (integer)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is there an integer that would satisfy an expression that looks like (fraction) MOD (int)?
For example, if we have the expression (1/5) MOD 10, could this expression have an integer result? If so, what would that integer result be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we take $\frac{1}{x}$ to denote the multiplicative inverse of $x$, working $\pmod{n}$, then certainly!

In general, $\frac{1}{x}$ exists in this situation only if $\gcd(x, n) = 1$. Because of this, notice that $\frac{1}{x}$ always exists when $x \neq 0$ and $n$ is prime (and hence, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a field).

Example:

$\frac{1}{3}$ exists $\pmod{10}$.  To find it, we apply the Euclidean algorithm and see that $3 \cdot -3 + 10 = 1$.  Modding this expression out by $10$, we get:

$$3 \cdot -3 = 3 \cdot 7 \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$$

Therefore, $\frac{1}{3} \equiv 7 \pmod{10}$.

Comment: That looks very confusing to me, haha. So, for example, what would be the integer result of (1/5) MOD 10? Just doing the MOD operation would give (1/5), but is it possible to get an integer solution to the equation x = (1/5) MOD 10? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It all depends on how we define $\frac{1}{5} \pmod{10}$.  If we take it to be the multiplicative inverse of $5$ in the ring of integers $\pmod{10}$ - i.e. the integer $x$ such that $5x \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$ - then it does not exist.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. What if you do the following though?: (1/5) DIV 10 = (1/5)/10 = 1/50, which has a remainder of 1.. So could you say that (1/5) MOD 10 is equivalent to 1 MOD 50, and, therefore, the answer is 1?